# Why does this set theory puzzle defy algebraic logic?

Tags: set-theory

I'm a middle school math enthusiast (I actually take beginning algebra 2 classes) obsessed with the concept of infinity. After several discussions with a high school math teacher, I was directed to the YouTube video, "Vsauce Counting Past Infinity," which in turn redirected me to the YouTube video, "The Supertask." In this clip, a mathematical puzzle is presented as follows:

1. A man, in half a minute, adds the numbers 1, 2... 10 into a bag, then takes out the one.
2. The man, in a quarter of a minute, adds the numbers 11, 12... 20 into a bag, then takes out the two.
3. The man continues this process, each time adding ten more numbers and taking away one in half the time he did it on the previous step.

The narrator then argues that, after one minute had passed (and, as a result, an infinite number of steps), there would be no numbers left in the bag, for there had been an infinite number of numbers added, each of which were matched with a step that took a number away.

I'm confused because this seems to defy basic algebra. Since the adding of ten can be represented as: $$y=10x$$ and the subtraction can be represented as: $$y=-x$$ X would literally have to be of two different values for y one plus y two to equal 0. I wouldn't be worried, accrediting it to the producer, however I see this fallacy again and again in set theory problems. Can anyone clarify the logic of this video for me? If higher level mathematical symbols are required, I'll look them up, just please explain, this has been pulling at me for months.

Comment: I think it comes down to limits of sets not being well-defined unless either each set contains the one before it (in which case we could make sense of the limit using union), or each set is contained in the one before it (in which case we may use intersection). In any other case, like the one here, there is no simple interpretation of the question "Which numbers are left in the end?"

Comment: What you're discovering is _discontinuity_ of operations (specifically set size) in the limit; while the size of the bag grows in every _finite_ step, for each number you can point to a _specific_ tick at which that number is removed from the bag, and so in set-theoretic terms we can speak of the 'limit' of the membership function as being the zero-function, and thus the limit of the set as being the empty set.

Comment: In some ways this is analagous to the 'fallacious' proof that $\sqrt{2}=2$, the 'Staircase Paradox' (see e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/2ltryq/the_staircase_paradox_a_sound_argument_that_the/ ) - the argument falls down under the belief that some function (arc length, or set size) is 'obviously' continuous in a space where it actually isn't.

Comment: The tag seems not to appropriate to your question. I recommend you to change a tag.

Comment: I apolagize, I am new to the website. What tag would you recommend, @HanulJeon?

Answer (score 0):

The laws of arithmetic for counting finite numbers of things do not apply to infinite sets.

After a finite number, $n,$ of steps, there are $9n$ numbers in the bag. But what if he put all the members of $\mathbb N$ into the bag on the first step and, afterwards, merely  removed the number $n$ on the $n$th step? Then after $n$ steps there are not $9n$ numbers in the bag, but an infinite number. And after one minute the bag is still empty.

Comment: Wait, wouldn't that process not be equivalent? As you describe it, there would be no difference (to my knowledge) between adding 9 numbers each time (in the original process) and adding 1. This is my main confusion when it comes to set theory, so please clarify.

Comment: There is no LAST step.  If $S_{j+1}$ always has more members than $S_j$ ,  then after a finite number, $n+1,$  of steps,  the set $S_{n+1}$ is not empty.......  But the common intersection of an infinite sequence  $(T_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ of infinite sets can be empty even if $T_{n+1}\subset T_n$ for every $ n.$  The rules of arithmetic are defined only for finite collections of finite sets and do not apply to infinite collections, so don't try to use them.......

Comment: Could you clarify what T stands for?

Comment: $T_n$  is just any infinite set.

Comment: I apologize if I'm misinterpreting anything you've said. Since $T_a$ marks an infinite step, and $S_b$ marks a finite one, wouldn't $a<b$? That would mean that $S_n+1<=T_n$, and that $T_n$ and $T_n+1$ would be greater than $0$, would it not?

Comment: $T_n$ in my A and comment is an infinite SET, not a step.